# mysql timeout - c/C++

Tags: c++, mysql, c

Guys i'm facing a problem with this code, the problem is the timeout by timeout i mean the

time it takes the program to tell me if the server is connected or not. If i use my

localhost i get the answer fast, but when i connect to outside my localhost it takes 50sc -

1.5 min to response and the program frezz until it done. HOw can i fix the frezzing, or make

my own timeout, like if still waiting after 50sc, tell me connection failed and stop?

please use codes as help, becouse i would understand it better, thanks for any help i get

PS: USING MAC

```
#include "mysql.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


// Other Linker Flags: -lmysqlclient -lm -lz 

// just going to input the general details and not the port numbers
struct connection_details
{
    char *server;
    char *user;
    char *password;
    char *database;
};

MYSQL* mysql_connection_setup(struct connection_details mysql_details)
{
    // first of all create a mysql instance and initialize the variables within
    MYSQL *connection = mysql_init(NULL);

    // connect to the database with the details attached.
    if (!mysql_real_connect(connection,mysql_details.server, mysql_details.user, mysql_details.password, mysql_details.database, 0, NULL, 0)) {
        printf("Conection error : %s\n", mysql_error(connection));
        exit(1);
    }
    return connection;
}



MYSQL_RES* mysql_perform_query(MYSQL *connection, char *sql_query)
{
    // send the query to the database
    if (mysql_query(connection, sql_query))
    {
        printf("MySQL query error : %s\n", mysql_error(connection));
        exit(1);
    }

    return mysql_use_result(connection);
}

int main()
{

        MYSQL *conn;        // the connection
    MYSQL_RES *res; // the results
    MYSQL_ROW row;  // the results row (line by line)

    struct connection_details mysqlD;
    mysqlD.server = (char*)"Localhost";  // where the mysql database is
    mysqlD.user =  (char*)"root";      // the root user of mysql   
    mysqlD.password =  (char*)"123456"; // the password of the root user in mysql
    mysqlD.database =  (char*)"test";  // the databse to pick

    // connect to the mysql database
    conn = mysql_connection_setup(mysqlD);

    // assign the results return to the MYSQL_RES pointer
    res = mysql_perform_query(conn, (char*) "SELECT * FROM me");


    printf("MySQL Tables in mysql database:\n");
    while ((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) !=NULL)
        printf("%s - %s\n", row[0], row[1], row[2]); // <-- Rows

    /* clean up the database result set */
    mysql_free_result(res);
    /* clean up the database link */
    mysql_close(conn);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The timeouts are within the TCP stack - you can probably do something to adjust them, but not until you tell your platform.

Comment: Im using Mac as platform

Comment: Are you sure that you change the basics of your code when you implement it outside the localhost? `mysqlD.server = (char*)"Localhost";` doesn't make sense in a non-localhost server

Moreover, does it connect when you implement it in another host? I mean that you said it freezes for sometime, but does it connect?

Comment: it connect to my Localhost, but not outside, it says failed or something, my only problem is the freezes

Comment: If it's only slow when you're connecting to the host remotely, then the slowness may be caused from the reverse DNS lookup that the server is performing. Take a look at [--skip-name-resolve](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve).

Answer (score 0):

If your main concern is the "freezes" (by which I think you mean that the UI is unresponsive while this connection attempt is made), then you should try creating a thread in which to run the connection code in the background, and meanwhile display a dialog that says "Connecting..." (or something) with a "Cancel" button so the user can give up if he/she wants to.  Try searching this site (or others) - there are plenty of examples and discussions of how to accomplish this.

Comment: i would love example from you, showing how to do it, it dosent have to be so hard , becouse i know you can make it real good.

Comment: Sorry.  I've never written a single line of code on a Mac, I have no idea what GUI library you're using, etc.  Try Google; it's your friend!  (StackOverflow isn't bad either!)